# Using diacritics

Tags: diacritics

I'm trying to figure out how to make the word Faro sound like Pharaoh as in the Egyptian Pharaoh instead of Far-Oh.

I'm looking into diacritics right now but they are confusing what I'm understanding so far I think is I would use a circumflex to change the A in Faro so it would look like this, Fâro. Am I correct if not can someone help me out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is unfortunately impossible; you have to use a separate guide to the pronunciation the way you do in this post ("as in the Egyptian Pharaoh"). "Fâro" has as wide a range of possible pronunciations as "Faro". See the similar question [English regarding the letter i being pronounced as ee](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235213)

Comment: [In some systems for Pronunciation respelling for English including American Heritage Dictionary notation, ă represents the so-called "short A" sound, /æ/.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%82)

Comment: @Jim: Hmm, but "Pharaoh" is generally pronounced with the "long a" sound, for people who distinguish these sounds in this position.

Comment: @sumelic - I pronounce it *fair-oh* not *fay-row*

Comment: @Jim: That's about syllabification or "[juncture](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/what-is-juncture-in-phonetics-and-or-phonology)", though, not vowel length per se. I don't pronounce "goalie" the same as "slowly" but both have a "long o" vowel. For some people, the vowel in words like "fair" and "fairy" is distinct from the vowel in words like "carry" and "marry". https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88115/how-are-marry-merry-and-mary-pronounced-differently

Comment: @sumelic- I convinced myself that it was approximately correct by starting to say the word *fat* which has the short ’a’ sound and before uttering the final ’t’ changing to say the ’r’ followed by ’oh’.  WhIch I thought was much closer to OP’s desired pronunciation.

Comment: I don't think English has any diacritical marks natively.

Comment: @Lawrence - http://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/the-curse-of-the-diaeresis

Comment: The marks exist, but I suspect they came with specific loan words - I don't think they're *native* to the English language. Even *cooperate*, mentioned in the article you linked to, is unadorned in standard English.

Comment: @sumelic It's not just about syllabification, but also simply vowel quality. _Fair(y)_ has /eə/ (syllabified after the consonant), _carry/marry_ has /a/ (also syllabified after the consonant), and _mayory_ has /eɪ/ (syllabified before the consonant). To me at least, only the third has the ‘long a’ sound; _pharaoh_ varies between the two first, never the third.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I would say the vowel quality is the phonetic realization of the phonological distinction based on syllabification/junction. I'm not familar with any phonemic analysis of North American English that postulates /eə/ as a distinct phoneme.

Comment: @sumelic So which phoneme would you say it is, then? /eɪ/ with syllabification after a following /r/? I suppose that would work… Even so, _pharaoh_ is quite commonly pronounced with a short /a/ as well, which basically just makes it unclear what exactly the asker is looking for. (I'm also curious as to how _goalie_ and _slowly_ differ phonetically for you—they're the same for me, apart from the initial consonant of course, and I don't recall ever registering a distinction in others either.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Well, I'm Mary/merry/marry merged, so my intuition doesn't necessarily apply for non-merged speakers, but I would say it is /eɪ/. I just realized the last sentence of my last comment is wrong--phonemic /eə/ seems to be necessary in accents that have ash-tensing with lexical exceptions to the rules. For me, "goalie" has a smoothed/velarized "o" (something like /oə̯/ or /o̞ə̯/, more or less the same vowel as I use in "gory") while "slowly" has a rising diphthong /oʊ/.

Answer (score 2):

English doesn't much use diacritics, but many folks do learn as schoolchildren (at least in the US) that a breve ˘ over a vowel means a "short" vowel, and a macron ¯ means a long vowel<sup>1</sup>. *Pharaoh* is pronounced with a *long*-a in the first syllable<sup>2</sup>, so you would want a macron over the *a* in Faro:

> ### Fāro

This is a solution that I've seen used by some brand names; one example is **Drāno**, which is pronounced like drain-oh:

[image: Close-up image of Drāno Max Gel, showing macron over the small letter a in the word Drano.] ([Photo by Mike Mozart](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jeepersmedia/14938294640))

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, in [this phonics lesson](http://www.actionfactor.com/pages/lesson-plans/v1.05-short-and-long-vowels.html).
<sup>2</sup> You can listen to [examples at Forvo.com](https://forvo.com/word/pharaoh/), as well as looking at pronunciation guides in dictionaries; some, like [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pharaoh), also include recordings)